# Numpy einsum broadcasting

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-einsum

Can someone please explain how broadcasting (ellipsis) works in the numpy.einsum() function?

Some examples to show how and when it can be used would be greatly appreciated.

I've checked the following official documentation page but there are only 2 examples and I can't seem to understand how to interpret it and use it.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html

Comment: There are more examples in the unittest file, https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/tests/test_einsum.py

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ellipses are a shorthand roughly standing for "all the remaining axes not explicitly mentioned". For example, suppose you had an array of shape (2,3,4,5,6,6):

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.random((2,3,4,5,6,6))
```

and you wish to take a trace along its last two axes:

```
result = np.einsum('ijklmm->ijklm', arr)
result.shape
# (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

An equivalent way to do that would be

```
result2 = np.einsum('...mm->...m', arr)
assert np.allclose(result, result2)
```

The ellipses provide a shorthand notation meaning (in this case) "and all the
axes to the left". The `...` stand for `ijkl`.

One nice thing about not having to be explicit is that

```
np.einsum('...mm->...m', arr)
```

works equally well with arrays of any number of dimensions >= 2 (so long as the last two have equal length), whereas

```
np.einsum('ijklmm->ijklm', arr)
```

only works when `arr` has exactly 6 dimensions.

---

When the ellipses appear in the middle, it is shorthand for "all the middle axes
not explicitly mentioned". For example, below, `np.einsum('ijklmi->ijklm', arr)`
is equivalent to `np.einsum('i...i->i...', arr)`. Here the `...` stand for `jklm`:

```
arr = np.random.random((6,2,3,4,5,6))
result = np.einsum('ijklmi->ijklm', arr)
result2 = np.einsum('i...i->i...', arr)
assert np.allclose(result, result2)
```